# Mysql multiple ON conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey so i try an upvote system this is my query

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO iDump_Upvote (UPV_Username, UPV_SujetId, UPV_Vote) 
        VALUES (:UPV_Username, :UPV_SujetId, :UPV_Vote) 
        ON UPV_VOTE = :UPV_Vote UPDATE UPV_VOTE = 0
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UPV_Vote = :UPV_Vote";
```

So it says : Insert if no duplicates, and if actual UPV_VOTE of row is equal to the one of the update, then put value back to 0

For example :

```
I click on the Upvote => insert => me - 123456 - 1
I click on downvote button => update => me - 123456 - -1
i click on the downvote button again => update => me - 123456 - 0
```

The query work fine whitout this line (but there is no 0 reset)

```
ON UPV_VOTE = :UPV_Vote UPDATE UPV_VOTE = 0
```

But it's not very clean to create another query which will basicly do

```
UPDATE iDump_Upvote (UPV_Vote) VALUES(0) WHERE UPV_Username = :UPV_Username AND UPV_SujetId = :UPV_SujetId AND UPV_Vote = :UPV_Vote
```

EDIT

This works :

```
"INSERT INTO iDump_Upvote (UPV_Username, UPV_SujetId, UPV_Vote) 
        VALUES (:UPV_Username, :UPV_SujetId, :UPV_Vote) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE UPV_Vote = CASE WHEN UPV_Vote = :UPV_Vote THEN 0 ELSE :UPV_Vote END";
```

thanks turo

Comment: How can a new row have an actual value?

Comment: well, if it already exist, it would have a value ! Thats why the "On duplicate key" is for

Comment: It has a value in the UPDATE-Part, use a case expression to UPD_Vote

Comment: Ups, I meant 'to UPDATE UPV_VOTE'

Comment: It works ! thanks a lot !